# logrotate saves content to old file

Tags: logging, logrotate

I used logrotate to rotate my log files. The conf file look like this:

```
/data/log/web/12114.log {

    daily

    rotate 10

    copytruncate

}
```

But logrotate doesn't cut the log file properly. The result log
files look like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root           0 12月 21 03:14 12114.log

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12806139570 12月 21 10:55 12114.log-20151217

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root           0 12月 17 03:13 12114.log-20151218

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root           0 12月 19 03:15 12114.log-20151219

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root           0 12月 20 03:28 12114.log-20151220

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root           0 12月 21 03:14 12114.log-20151221
```

Which means all the logs were written to `12114.log-20151217`, the 
should-be file `12114.log-20151221` has no content.

Why could this happen? The log file were written from `flask logger
utils`.

Thx in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Logrotate just moves/renames the file, but your snippet above will do nothing to tell the running process that the file has been moved.  You will need a postrotate stanza in your logrotate config that tells the process to reopen its log file, closing the moved one and opening the original again.

Comment: No, this should be wrong because alex is using `copytruncate`.  However it looks like something else may be overriding this logrotate entry and that something does not have `copytruncate` and also no postrotate that signals the correct process.

Comment: You make a splendid point; with only 5 lines of config I don't know how I missed the copytruncate.   I have seen problems with Java and copytruncate before, but not as presented above.